# Eclipse plug-in: bind data to a list and refresh view

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am working on an Eclipse **plugin-project** where I have multiple services which have to **register** themselves to the master-project (stored in a list). I have one **view where I want to list each service** (that successfully registered itself) **and its status** (if enabled/disabled -> from settings) which should be updated if the **status changes**.

**What i tried:**
The adding works as expected and the list in the master-project knows the single services. Now I have problems to show the details (service + it's status). I tried to add a new label for each service (with a for-each-loop). Basically this works, but I don't know how to refresh the view after I get the event (in the view) that a service was added. Moreover I don't know how to bind the propertychanged-event to such a label. (I know how to do it if the labels are hard coded, but that's not possible here).

How can I achieve what I want? (show label & status for each registered service and refresh status if it changes)

Thank you!!

Comment: How about using a JFace TableViewer with columns for service name and state?

Comment: Thanks. For optical reasons, I don't want to use a TableViewer. I prefer a list of stacked labels. They look like a table, but there shouldn't be any borders. Thanks for your help...

Comment: I solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234090/how-to-update-refresh-a-view-in-an-eclipse-plug-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I add my answer/solution I found here:
[Eclipse plug-in: bind data to a list and refresh view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049333/eclipse-plug-in-bind-data-to-a-list-and-refresh-view)