# How to update/refresh a view in an eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, view

I have an **eclipse plug-in** with a single **view** (like the eclipse helloworld-view-plugin-project). In the view-file I get an **event when I want to update the view**.

In this view I have a GridData in a Group with multiple labels. I have several **services which register to the programe and whose status should be shown** in this GridData.

Edit: In order to better show my problem I updated this post and added the whole code:

---

**CreatePartControl():**

```
public void createPartControl(Composite _parent) {
  parent = _parent;
  createContents();
  addBindings();
  makeActions();
  contributeToActionBars();
}
```

**CreateContents():**

```
protected void createContents() {

  // fixed
  checkIcon = //...
  errorIcon = //...
  smallFont = SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 7, SWT.NORMAL);

  // content
  gl_shell = new GridLayout(1, false);
  //margins, etc. for gl_shell
  parent.setLayout(gl_shell);

  final Label lblGreeting = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
  lblGreeting.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 1));
  lblGreeting.setText("Hi " + Preferences.getPreName());

  // -- GROUP YOUR STATS (show all services)
  createStatusGroupBox();
}
```

**createStatusGroupBox():**

```
private Group grpYourStatus = null; // outside the method for access in listener (below)

private void createStatusGroupBox() {
  grpYourStatus = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
  grpYourStatus.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1));
  grpYourStatus.setText("Your upload status");
  grpYourStatus.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

  // add message if no service is registered
  if ( r.getServiceList().size() == 0 ) {
     Label status = new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE);
     status.setText("No service registered.");
     new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE); //empty
     new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE); //empty
  }

  // add labels (status, message, name) for each registered service
  for ( IRecorderObject service : r.getServiceList() ) {
     Label name = new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE);
     Label status = new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE);
     Label message = new Label(grpYourStatus, SWT.NONE);
     message.setFont(smallFont);
     message.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

     service.getServiceViewItem().setLabelsAndIcons(name, status, message, checkIcon, errorIcon); //this also sets the values of the labels (label.setText(...) via data binding)
}
```

---

Unfortunately, I don't know what the right way is to update/reset it. I tried the following:

**listener (which should update the view / the services-list):**

```
r.addPropertyChangeListener(BindingNames.SERVICE_ADDED, new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {   
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // This "redraws" the view, but just places the whole content (generated in createStatusGroupBox()) above the other parts.
        //Display.getCurrent().update();
        //createStatusGroupBox();
        //parent.layout(true);
        //parent.redraw();

        // disposes grpYourStatus-Group but doesn't show anything then
        grpYourStatus.dispose();
        createStatusGroupBox();
        grpYourStatus.layout();
        grpYourStatus.redraw(); 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I also tried the following statements (individually); all without success:

```
parent.redraw();
parent.update();
parent.layout();
parent.layout(true);
parent.refresh();
```

---

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352718/how-to-refresh-eclipse-view-plugin) I read the following:

> createPartControls is that time of the life cycle of a view, where its
>   contained widgets are created (when the view becomes visible
>   initially). This code is only executed once during the view life
>   cycle, therefore you cannot add anything here directly to refresh your
>   view.
>
> Eclipse parts typically update their content as a reaction to a
>   changed selection inside of the workbench (e.g. the user might click
>   on another stack frame in the debug view).

Unfortunately, I don't know what to else I could try and I didn't find anything helpful with searches... **thank's for your help and suggestions**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer (together with AndreiC's help!):

my listener now looks like this:

```
r.addPropertyChangeListener(BindingNames.SERVICE_ADDED, new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {   
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         // remove grpYourStatus from parent
         grpYourStatus.dispose();

         // add grpYourStatus (with updated values) to parent
         createStatusGroupBox();

         // refresh view
         parent.pack();
         parent.layout(true);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The rest is the same like the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the API by heart, but have you tried `parent.update()`?

Comment: Thanks Andrei for your answer. Yes, I have tried that also (added to my post). Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t31866.html) is useful.

Comment: Thanks for this post. It's great, but I couldn't make it work... I tried the following:

`grpYourStatus.dispose();
createStatusGroupBox();
grpYourStatus.layout();      
grpYourStatus.redraw();`

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your entire code (the createPartControl at least)?

Comment: hi AndreiC. Thanks very much for trying to help me. I edited my first post and added all the code. There also is some code that is not important for the problem but I wanted to avoid errors while shortening the code. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but i am currently very busy; have you tried to refresh/redraw parent and grpYourStatus, something like: parent.redraw() and then grpYourStatus.layout(true)? (also, just a silly question, but, the propertyChange does get triggered, right?)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, without success... At the moment I think I might do it on the wrong thread...? At the moment I am trying to do it with (Display.getDefault().asyncExec(Runnable)). You see my code in my first post. Thank you!

Comment: Now I did it. In the PropertyChangedListener in the run()-method I added the following code:
||  grpYourStatus.dispose();  
createStatusGroupBox();  
parent.layout(true); || That did it... thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool, sorry i could not help you out more (am pretty busy at the moment :( ). Also, please copy the code sequence above, which made it work and post in a separate answer and mark that as solved ;). You are the one who did it, not me - it will be more useful to others as well than our discussion. All the best!